# Implementation for CombineFileInputFormat Hadoop 0.20.205

Tags: java, mapreduce, inputformatter

Can someone please point out where I could find an implementation for `CombineFileInputFormat` (org. using Hadoop 0.20.205? this is to create large splits from very small log files (text in lines) using EMR.

It is surprising that Hadoop does not have a default implementation for this class made specifically for this purpose and googling it looks like I'm not the only one confused by this. I need to compile the class and bundle it in a jar for hadoop-streaming, with a limited knowledge of Java this is some challenge.

Edit:
I already tried the yetitrails example, with the necessary imports but I get a compiler error for the next method.

Comment: What errors do you get with the yeti trails example? It seems ok to me.

Comment: have u seen this: http://yaseminavcular.blogspot.com/2011/03/many-small-input-files.html

Comment: @Charles, thank you, the error I get is "error: MyKeyValueLineRecordReader is not abstract and does not override abstract method next(Object,Object) in RecordReader"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an implementation I have for you:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileRecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileSplit;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CombinedInputFormat extends CombineFileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text> {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf conf, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        return new CombineFileRecordReader(conf, (CombineFileSplit) split, reporter, (Class) myCombineFileRecordReader.class);
    }

    public static class myCombineFileRecordReader implements RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        private final LineRecordReader linerecord;

        public myCombineFileRecordReader(CombineFileSplit split, Configuration conf, Reporter reporter, Integer index) throws IOException {
            FileSplit filesplit = new FileSplit(split.getPath(index), split.getOffset(index), split.getLength(index), split.getLocations());
            linerecord = new LineRecordReader(conf, filesplit);
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            linerecord.close();

        }

        @Override
        public LongWritable createKey() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return linerecord.createKey();
        }

        @Override
        public Text createValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return linerecord.createValue();
        }

        @Override
        public long getPos() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return linerecord.getPos();
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return linerecord.getProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return linerecord.next(key, value);
        }

    }
}
```

In your job first set the parameter `mapred.max.split.size` according to the size you would like the input files to be combined into. Do something like follows in your *run()*:

```
...
            if (argument != null) {
                conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", argument);
            } else {
                conf.set("mapred.max.split.size", "134217728"); // 128 MB
            }
...

            conf.setInputFormat(CombinedInputFormat.class);
...
```

Comment: Hi @Amar, Where is the index coming from?

Comment: @ManikandanKannan : you need not worry about index while using this InputFormat. In order to use it just do `conf.setInputFormat(CombinedInputFormat.class);` as shown above. But FYI index is perhaps the split number which is passed on while intializing the record reader internally by hadoop.

Comment: Thank you very much! A job that took 1 hour and 40 minutes before this solution now only takes 5 minutes.
Also, the WholeFileRecordReader comes from the Tom White book. Thanks for making so much comments elucidating its source code :)
Well done!

Comment: Brillent, My Job Changed from 30 min to 2 min using this combiner. My Each small file was of 5 mb each and was spanning 4000 mappers previously comp[ared to 71 mappers with this combiner

Comment: @Prometheus .. I have used this CombinedInputFormat implementation for small files...but no. of mappers have reduced from 100 to 25 but the seen but the job took more time for execution in later case from (100 minutes to 33 minutes.)..can you tell me what was your before and after job, confs?   Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107504/does-using-combinefileinputformat-for-small-files-gives-performance-improvement

Comment: @astro the code is at: https://github.com/MarcoLotz/HadoopLung, in a folder called I/O or something like it. The number of mappers is equivalent to the number of input splits. Check if your code matches mine :)

Comment: I am testing the performance improvement using combinFileInputFormat. with my experiment I don't see any performace improvement..can someone point me to the complete demo of before and after performace improvement code.. @ArghoChatterjee

Comment: @Amar, is there any post that shows code before using this combinFileInputFormat and after using combinFileInputFormat. I want to benchmark these cases. I was unable to get any performance improvement using above code.