# How to bundle custom hadoop-streaming.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, streaming, mrjob

I'm trying to use the `CombineFileInputFormat` class using Yelp's MrJob tool for EMR. The jobflow is created using hadoop streaming, and MrJob's documentation indicates the `CombineFileInputFormat` class must be bundled in a customized `hadoop-streaming.jar`.

For context, please follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205).

Specifically my question is: Where should the concrete class `CombinedInputFormat.class` be bundled or referenced within the `hadoop-streaming.jar`?

I have tried bundling the `CombinedInputFormat.class` by adding it to a directory `org/apache/hadoop/streaming` and executing:

```
jar uvf my-hadoop-streaming.jar org/apache/hadoop/streaming
```

If I do that, the streaming jobflow starts, with the option `-inputformat CombinedInputFormat` the Job starts the first step and breaks, with error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/streaming/CombinedInputFormat (wrong name: CombinedInputFormat)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        ...
```

If I just try to set it in the root path with:

```
jar uvf my-hadoop-streaming.jar CombinedInputFormat.class
```

The error I get is:

```
-inputformat : class not found : CombinedInputFormat
Streaming Job Failed!
```

How should I bundle the CombinedInputFormat.class so that it will be correctly taken and solve the `NoClassDefFoundError` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `CombinedInputFormat` explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205) extends `CombineFileInputFormat` and isn't ported with hadoop. So what you need to do is, in the same package where you have you mapper/reducer job class, you have to CREATE a class and have the code stated in the earlier issue. Then create jar and it should run normally.

So basically, you need to write your own implementation of `CombineFileInputFormat`(which I did it for you) and you can name it anything you want, say `ABCClass` instead of `CombinedInputFormat` as I had named it.

Comment: Thanks Amar, I found the class not found error was caused by not having the package statement at the beginning of the custom class module. I have this working, but one more question, this works very well to read raw lines of text, but I am having trouble trying to implement a class using KeyValueLineRecordReader. Specifically I get a problem with the next() method which seems to require arguments of type (Object, Object), but the compiler complains on the return line saying it needs to return type (Text, Text). What can be causing this paradox?

Comment: OK so you need to be specific about the generic types you are referring to here. Perhaps the class your are creating is like : `MyClass extends KeyValueLineRecordReader` , but instead you should be doing something like : `MyClass extends KeyValueLineRecordReader<Text,Text>`.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I realized last night it was the case, after that fix it runs smoothly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is another easy way i found to get custom jar built and run in hadoop local or EMR
http://www.applams.com/2014/05/using-custom-streaming-jar-using-custom.html