# how can i work with large number of small files in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

i am new to hadoop and i'm working with large number of small files in wordcount example.
it takes a lot of map tasks and results in slowing my execution.

how can i reduce the number of map tasks??

if the best solution to my problem is catting small files to a larger file, how can i cat them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using something like `TextInputFormat`, the problem is that each file has at least 1 split, so the upper bound of the number of maps is the number of files, which in your case where you have many very small files you will end up with many mappers processing each very little data.

To remedy to that, you should use `CombineFileInputFormat` which will pack multiple files into the same split (I think up to the block size limit), so with that format the number of mappers will be independent of the number of files, it will simply depend on the amount of data.

You will have to create your own input format by extending from `CombineFileInputFormt`, you can find an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284330/1332690). Once you have your `InputFormat` defined, let's called it like in the link `CombinedInputFormat`, you can tell your job to use it by doing:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(CombinedInputFormat.class);
```

Comment: if i wanted to maintain the id of small files, what do i do? Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

Cloudera posted a [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) on small files problem sometime back. It's an old entry, but the suggested method still applies.