# Is InputSplit size or number of map tasks affected by the number of input files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Would it make a difference to the number of map tasks spawned by a job if I have a lot of small files (~HDFS block size) vs a few large files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends which `InputFormat` you use, because this is what determines the input splits computation, and thus the number of map tasks.

If you use the default `TextInputFormat`, each file will have at least 1 split, so at least 1 mapper per file, even if these files are a few kB, each mapper doing very little work, but this introduces a lot of overhead for the Map/Reduce framework. That said if you have a guarantee that these "small" files will be close to the block size, that probably doesn't matter too much.

If you have no control over your files and they might get really small, I would advise using a different `InputFormat` called `CombineFileInputFormat` which combines several input files in the same split, the number of maps in this case will only depend on the overall amount of data, regardless of the number of files. An implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284330/1332690).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was very descriptive and informational. Also  If I have a choice between modifying the way data is written to HDFS (large files) vs using CombineFileInputFormat, How do we decide and what parameters affect the decision?