# Hadoop smaller input file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am using hadoop in a little different way. In my case, input size is really small. However, computation time is more. I have some complicated algorithm which I will be running on every line of input. So even though the input size is less than 5mb, the overall computation time is over 10hrs. So I am using hadoop here. I am using NLineInputFormat to split the file by number of lines rather than block size. In my initial testing, I had around 1500 lines (Splitting by 200 lines) and I saw only a improvement of 1.5 times in a four node cluster compared to that of running it serially on one machine. I am using VM's. Could that be the issue or for smaller size input there wont be much benefits with hadoop? Any insights will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your workload resembles SETI@Home work load -- small payloads but hours of crunching time.

Hadoop (or more specifically HDFS) is not designed for lots of small files.  But I doubt that is an issue for MapReduce - the processing framework you are using.

If you want to keep your workload together:
1) split them into individual files (one workload, one file)  if the file is less than block size then it will go to one mapper.  Typical block sizes are 64MB or 128MB

2) create a wrapper for FileInputFormat, and override the 'isSplitable()' method to false.  This will make sure entire file contents are fed to one mapper, rather than hadoop trying to split it line by line

reference : http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_book/HDFS_Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there any disadvantage with splitting it line by line? Just to summarize, you mean that I should be splitting input file into smaller files. Lets say I create 8 files with each having n/8 lines. Ans then I should be doing the point number 2 which you have mentioned above? I am not understanding the advantage by doing this over splitting it line by line. In my case I am splitting it by in the form of (total lines/total nodes). It is not actually single line.

Comment: 1) 
does one 'record' fits in one line?  If so then let hadoop do the splitting.
If your 'record' spans multiple lines, then you will need to take control of splitting.

2) if you let hadoop do splitting,   then have your input not in one file, but multiple files.  This way, the processing will be parallelized between nodes (more specifically mappers) -- without you having to do any special work

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Hadoop is not really good at dealing with tons of small files, hence, it is often desired to combine a large number of smaller input files into less number of bigger files so as to reduce number of mappers.

As Input to Hadoop MapReduce process is abstracted by `InputFormat`. `FileInputFormat` is a default implementation that deals with files in HDFS. With `FileInputFormat`, each file is split into one or more `InputSplits` typically upper bounded by `block size`. This means the number of input splits is lower bounded by number of input files. This is not an ideal environment for MapReduce process when it’s dealing with large number of small files, because overhead of coordinating distributed processes is far greater than when there is relatively large number of small files.

The basic parameter which drives the spit size is `mapred.max.split.size`.

Using `CombineFileInputFormat` and this parameter we can control the number of mappers.

Checkout the implementation I had for another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205/14284330#14284330).

Comment: Thanks Amar. But as I mentioned, in my case I have just 1 input file. And even that is very very small in size, less than 5mb. However, the execution time is large and that is why I am using MapReduce to distribute among a set of nodes. To be more clear, I have 40k lines in input file and 4 nodes in cluster. Instead of splitting file by block size, I am doing by number of lines. I am giving it as 10k. By doing this, each node will get 10k lines. But the problem is with overall performance. I am just seeing 1.5 times improvement in a 4 node cluster compared to that of running it serially.