# how to convert text files of size KB into Sequence File

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have huge amount of data stored in HDFS, but the individual files are very small (KBs). So the MapReduce processing is taking a lot of time.

Can I reduce the processing time? Will SequenceFile be a good option?

Please provide some Java or MR code to convert multiple smaller text files into SequenceFile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SequenceFile would be a good choice in such a scenario. You could do something like this :

```
public class TextToSequenceConverter {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path inputFile = new Path("/infile");
        FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(inputFile);
        Path outputFile = new Path("/outfile");
        IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
        int count = 0;
        Text value = new Text();    
        String str;
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf,outputFile, key.getClass(), value.getClass());
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            key.set(count++);
            str = inputStream.readLine();
            value.set(str);
            writer.append(key, value);
        }
        fs.close();
        IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
        System.out.println("SEQUENCE FILE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY........");
    }
}
```

You might also wanna have a look at HAR files.

You might find this a good read :
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/

---

To convert all the files inside a HDFS directory into a single Sequence file :

```
package my.pack;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class BundleSeq {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path(
                "/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path(
                "/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path inputFile = new Path("/bundleinput");
        Path outputFile = new Path("/outfile");
        FSDataInputStream inputStream;
        Text key = new Text();
        Text value = new Text();
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(fs, conf,
                outputFile, key.getClass(), value.getClass());
        FileStatus[] fStatus = fs.listStatus(inputFile);

        for (FileStatus fst : fStatus) {
            String str = "";
            System.out.println("Processing file : " + fst.getPath().getName() + " and the size is : " + fst.getPath().getName().length());
            inputStream = fs.open(fst.getPath());
            key.set(fst.getPath().getName());
            while(inputStream.available()>0) {
                str = str+inputStream.readLine();
            }
            value.set(str);
            writer.append(key, value);

        }
        fs.close();
        IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
        System.out.println("SEQUENCE FILE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY........");
    }
}
```

Here filename is the key and file content is the value.

Comment: Thanks for your response .
Here inputfile path will take only files. But i have many files in a single directory and i want to combine those files into single sequenceFile.

Comment: Well, you have not specified that you need all the files in a directory to be clubbed together as a Seq file. See the second piece of code above.

Answer (score 0):

You may override `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat` and create your `CombinedInputFormat`. For implementation see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284330/610305). And by setting the parameter `mapred.max.split.size` you may control the size you would like the input files to be combined into.

For more read [here](http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/01/how-to-combine-input-files-to-get-to_11.html).