# Is there a combine Input format for hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, streaming

I have many small input files, and I want to combine them using some input format like `CombineFileInputFormat` to launch fewer mapper tasks. I know I can use Java API to do this, but I don't know whether there's a streaming jar library to support this function while I'm using Hadoop streaming.

Answer (score 3):

Hadoop streaming uses `TextInputFormat` by default but any other input format can be used, including `CombineFileInputFormat`. You can change the input format from the command line, using the option `-inputformat`. Be sure to use the old API and implement `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat`. The new API isn't supported yet.

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar \
      $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
      -inputformat foo.bar.MyCombineFileInputFormat \
      -Dmapred.max.split.size=524288000 \
      -Dstream.map.input.ignoreKey=true \
      ...
```

[Example of CombineFileInputFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205)