# Best way for Hadoop to handle lots of image files

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

I've successfully managed to handle multiple image files in 2 ways in Hadoop:

1. Using Java to stitch images together using a sequence file. This requires a text file that points to the locations of all the files.
2. Using Python and Hadoop streaming to cache files to each node using -cacheArchive in the form of a tar.gz archive.

Both methods seem a bit ropey to me. Let's say I have one million files, I do not want to have to create the text file or zip up so many files. Is there a way i can just point my mapper to an hdfs folder and have it read through that folder at runtime? I know input can be used, but this is for text files. Or am I missing something? Any pointers are most appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of `CombinedInputFormat`? I can't help with you code, but here is a nice article on it http://analog99.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/hadoop-combineinputformat/

Comment: Thanks! And for using it with Hadoop Streaming, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485535/is-there-a-combine-input-format-for-hadoop-streaming)  and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205) look useful.