# Number of mappers for a Mapreduce program

Tags: mapreduce

How Many Mappers are going to executed if my mapreduce  job read 60 files each 1 mb of size availabe in a directory. Lets assume under this /user/cloudera/inputs/ directory there are 60 files and size of each file is 1 mb

In my configuration class of  mapreduce i specified the directory /user/cloudera/inputs/.

Can somebody tell me how many blocks are used for storing that 60 files of each 1 mb size and How many mappers are executed

Is it 60 blocks and 60 mappers?If it is so Somebody explain me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map tasks usually process a block of input at a time (using the default FileInputFormat). If the file is very small and there are a lot of them, then each map task processes very little input, and there are a lot more map tasks, each of which imposes extra bookkeeping overhead. Compare a 1GB file broken into 16 64MB blocks, and 10,000 or so 100KB files. The 10,000 files use one map each, and the job time can be tens or hundreds of times slower than the equivalent one with a single input file.

```
In your case 60 map are used in 60 files and used 60 blocks.
```

If you're using something like TextInputFormat, the problem is that each file has at least 1 split, so the upper bound of the number of maps is the number of files, which in your case where you have many very small files you will end up with many mappers processing each very little data.

To remedy to that, you should use CombineFileInputFormat which will pack multiple files into the same split (I think up to the block size limit), so with that format the number of mappers will be independent of the number of files, it will simply depend on the amount of data.

You will have to create your own input format by extending from CombineFileInputFormt, you can find an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270317/implementation-for-combinefileinputformat-hadoop-0-20-205/14284330#14284330). Once you have your InputFormat defined, let's called it like in the link CombinedInputFormat, you can tell your job to use it by doing:

```
job.setInputFormatClass(CombinedInputFormat.class);
```